# delete element from list with R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list of words

```
 [[1]]    
  [1] Hello
  [2] all    
  [3] the    
  [4] world
 [[2]]
  [1] world 
  [2] my  
  [3] Hi
```

And a data frame which contains for each word its frequency in the text:

```
Var1    Freq 
Hello   54 
all     178 
the     53 
entire  57
world   49
```

I would like to know if is there any way to remove each string of the data frame from the list of strings. For example as a result I will have, if I delete the word "Hello"
I will get:

```
  [[1]]    
    [1] all    
    [2] the    
    [3] world
   [[2]]
    [1] world 
    [2] my  
    [3] Hi
```

PS: Another example of @Julius

```
 (l <- list(letters[1:2], letters[2:3]))

# [[1]]    
# [1] "a" "b"    
# [[2]]   
# [1] "b" "c" 

(r <- letters[2])

# [1] "b"

The result will be like this :

     [1] "c"
```

because all the letters before "b" with "b" are deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(l <- list(letters[1:2], letters[2:3]))
# [[1]]
# [1] "a" "b"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "b" "c"
(r <- letters[2])
# [1] "b"
lapply(l, setdiff, r)
# [[1]]
# [1] "a"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "c"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. r must be a list? because in my case is a dataframe? Cheers

Comment: @Fish, instead of `r` you may use simply `df$Var1`.

Comment: I still have a problem, I edit my post with your example to see better the problem. Cheers

Comment: @Fish, I don't understand the problem. Please also show the line that you use to get only `[1] "b"` because you are using the same example data as I do, so I cannot see how you can get different results.

Comment: I talk about my objectiv, not about what your fucntion do. In fact I would lik to delete all the letter coming before "b"

Comment: @Fish, I assumed that your update is a problematic output, not the expected one. So you want to specify a single character `x` and then in every list element to delete everything before `x` and `x` itself? It sounds like a different, even though related, question than the original one, isn't it?

Comment: Yes that's right , this is what i am looking for. I know it is a little be difficult

Comment: @Fish Removing elements before/after some letter appears to be a different question. Please ask it in a separate post. Don't forget to include a reproducible example.

Comment: @Fish, it is not a very difficult problem, but it is quite different than the original one (as I understand, I did answer your original question correctly), so I suggest to post a separate question instead.

Comment: Ok, I will do now. Thank you